# How to know triggered plugins by (root) plugin?

Tags: sbt

How to find out what are the triggered plugins of a root plugin?

Let's consider the Play plug-in

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.0")
```

What further plug-ins are enabled (triggered) if this plugin is?

(Cross-posted at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/DyTm-5VQRiM)

Comment: This may not be fully implemented in sbt 0.13.5.   I believe the index is available, but the full rich user interface not as much.   Partly due to binary compatibility restrictions and partly due to time restrictions.

Comment: @jsuereth Thanks for your reply! Any suggestions for an interim solution?

Comment: Try the `plugins` command on the console.